# update unique id to table base on phone or email address in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

currently i have following table structure in `sql server2008 r2`

```
  tbusertable
    userid username  uid   status
      1    abc       null  null
      2    yax       null  null
      3    xcd       null  null
      4    max       null  null
      5    wax       null  null
      6    ear       null  null
      7    yes       null  null
      8    sqt       null  null
      9    ora       null  null 



 tbphtable 
    pid userid phnos 
    1    1     456 
    2    2     456
    3    3     4568
    4    4     789
    5    5     5555
    6    6     4599
    7    7     456
    8    8     111
    9    9     111



tbeidtable 
    eid userid eid
    1    1     y@gmail.com
    2    2     abd@gmail.com
    3    3     erer@gmail.com
    4    4     yer@gmail.com
    5    5     g@gmail.com
    6    6     g@gmail.com
```

i want to update `uid` column of `tbusertable` table with unique id, if they have same `phnos` for `eid` without cursor because table have large records and cursor take long time to run

desire output

`userid 1,2,7` have same `phnos` so they have same unique id and similarly
`userid 5,6` have same `eid` so they have different  unique id 
and similarly `userid 8,9` have same `phnos` so they have same different unique id

```
  tbusertable
        userid username  uid                                   status
          1    abc       D7CCBC4E-EEE6-4AC8-806D-A04DCC77DF54  null
          2    yax       D7CCBC4E-EEE6-4AC8-806D-A04DCC77DF54  null
          3    xcd       null  null
          4    max       0608CFF7-3FC6-4952-91AE-5E42D6558827  null
          5    wax       0608CFF7-3FC6-4952-91AE-5E42D6558827  null
          6    ear       null                                  null
          7    yes       D7CCBC4E-EEE6-4AC8-806D-A04DCC77DF54  null
          8    sqt       5823E1FD-2AF3-4BA7-8C48-946A16E0D3E2  null
          9    ora       5823E1FD-2AF3-4BA7-8C48-946A16E0D3E2  null
```

Comment: And where does the `uid` come from?

Comment: i have generated using newid() function in sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can calculate the new ids for each phone number using a subquery and then use this for the update:

```
update u
    set uid = pp.new_uid
    from tbusertable u join
         tbphtable p
         on u.userid = p.userid join
         (select phnos, newid() as new_uid
          from tbphtable
          group by phnos
         ) pp
         on p.phnos = pp.phnos;
```

EDIT:

Because of how SQL Server optimizes queries, you might need to put the newids in a temporary table:

```
select phnos, newid() as new_uid
into #pp
from tbphtable
group by phnos;
```

And then:

```
update u
    set uid = pp.new_uid
    from tbusertable u join
         tbphtable p
         on u.userid = p.userid join
         #pp pp
         on p.phnos = pp.phnos;
```

SQL Server can rewrite queries, resulting in functions being called more commonly than expected.  Putting the values in a temporary table should solve that problem.

Comment: i generating different unique id for same phnos  eg userid 1,2 it has generated uid as 4EE998DE-0021-4569-AB52-D1380C800691,
6DB4B434-093A-4D8E-BDFC-1BFE100794D0 i

Comment: and how to do for userid have same eid eg 5 and 6 having  same eid